# Windows 10 Camera App doesn't work

Tags: windows-10, camera

My camera app seems to 'open', but then just shows a grid with settings & other icons and  black screen background but no picture or video.

I can toggle between 'camera' & 'video' icons but neither of them produces any pictures on the screen. Also an error message indicates that some other app might be using the camera.

I used the camera a long time ago to make a video, so it worked at one point.

Comment: Did you verify if the camera itself works? E.g. on a random website for checking that.

Comment: Which camera app?

Comment: Is there anything covering the camera lens?

Answer (score 0):

The error message that some other app might be using the camera might
block your camera app from using the camera.

To find which app is using the camera :

- Run *Settings > Privacy > Camera*
- Scroll down to "Allow desktop apps to access your camera"
- Verify that the last entry in the list is from today.

When you know which other app has taken control of the camera, you might
be able to block it (or use it as your camera app).